# Groovy MarkUpBuilder with local files

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

Im little stuck with XML. Path in `sqlfile` in XML must be taken from folders where are SQLfiles loaded by using `dir` and `dir1` I have problem to build XML like that :

```
<databaseChangeLog

<changeSet author="John" id="JRIA" failOnError="true" runAlways="false">
    <sqlFile path="path.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8" />
    <rollback>
        <sqlFile path="rollback/path.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8" />
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

My example :

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.xml.*


def dir = new File("C:\\Users\\John\\git\\changelogs\\version1\\db")
def dir1 = new File("C:\\Users\\John\\git\\changelogs\\version1\\rollback")

def sw = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)
xml.changeSet(author:"John", ID:"JIRA", failOnError: "True", runAlways: "false"){
    sqlFile(path:"From DIR", relativeToChangelogFile="true")
    rollback(){
        sqlFile(path:"From DIR1", relativeToChangelogFile="true")}
}
```

How to use `dir`  and `dir1` in good way to generate that XML ? And how get specific extension files (sql)

Answer (score 0):

it was quite simple, just use `.each`

```
xml.dataBaseChangeLog(){
dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->   
    changeSet(author:"John", ID:"JIRA", failOnError: "True", runAlways: "false")
    sqlFile(path:file, relativeToChangelogFile="true")    
    rollback(){       
        sqlFile(path:file, relativeToChangelogFile="true")
}}}
```